How can I hide ReplyMarkup and show InlineKeyboardMarkup without sending a new message?
I am trying this for now, using python-telegram-bot==20.6:
async def callback(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    buttons = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton(text="CONFIG", callback_data="CONFIG"), CANCEL_BUTTON]
    ]
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(buttons)
    # remove normal markup
    msg = await update.message.reply_text(text="Select an action", reply_markup=ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    # add inline markup
    await msg.edit_reply_markup(keyboard)
    return SELECT_ACTION

What is strange here is I get error telegram.error.BadRequest: Message can't be edited, where the message being edited is the one in the update, not msg...
